# Removing icon from menu-bar

Tags: menu-bar

Does anyone know how to permanently remove an icon put in the menu bar by DYMO label maker software?  I can right click it and remove it, or drag it off the menu bar.  However, it returns upon a reboot.

Comment: Have you contacted the maker of the software and asked them how to remove it?

Comment: Check `System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items` tab to see if the DYMO software is set to open when you login. If it is there, select it and click the minus sign icon to delete. If you have the original software installer, perhaps there is an uninstall function. Which model of labeler do you have?

Answer (score 3):

So I downloaded dyno marker software on my Mac for you and I found a simple solution to your problem but before I tell you the solution, make sure of the following:

1. DYMO label marker app should be quit
2. Make sure the app is in your Applications folder

After making sure then run the following in terminal app:

`rm /Applications/DYMO\ Label.app/Contents/Resources/DYMO\ Label.icns`

Then open the app and check if you are still able to see the icon in the menubar.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and this didn't work for me. The Dymo software doesn't even appear in the login items, so how are they making it load at startup? Nobody should download this app. It's terrible.

Comment: Also, Bartender shows DYMO.dls.printing.host in it's list of menu items, but when I search the whole mac I can't find that anywhere.

Comment: Have you tried removing it after installing App Cleaner?  when you delete the app, App cleaner finds related files and offers to delete them too. Maybe this is what you need.

Comment: I finally got it! The Dymo installs the library files directly on the Macintosh HD. When you open a finder window and navigate to "Library", you're actually in the library folder for the user account, not the one on the HD. Finder searches and App Cleaner searches didn't reveal it, even if Finder is told to search "This Mac".